# Is Thread#raise safe in MRI Ruby 1.9/2.0?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

So there's an old blog post about the unsafe-ness of Thread#raise, Thread#kill, and by extension Timeout (http://headius.blogspot.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html). Java deprecated its equivalent methods long ago for about the same reasons (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

The blog post is very old. Are modern implementations of Thread.raise safe? If so, is there documentation/commits to prove/demonstrate it?

Answer (score 3):

No they're still not safe (at least in ruby).  https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/timeout.rb is the latest code you can see it still does a `x.raise exception` in there.  This can do bad things like if you have nested timeouts, they can conflict with each other [yikes].  FWIW.